# How to return a record in a function in SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write a function that returns in INT which is the number of records that match a certain criteria.

I tried this, and it runs... but it keeps quiet - it doesn't return anything. I guess it just runs select in the background.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_InboundCallsPerUser](@p_User varchar(50), @p_sd datetime, @p_ed datetime)
RETURNS INT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
Return(SELECT  COUNT(*) 
FROM CallDetail
WHERE LocalUserID = @p_user
AND InitiatedDate BETWEEN @p_sd AND @p_ed
AND UPPER(CallDirection) = 'OUTBOUND'
AND LineDurationSeconds > 0);
END;
```

How do you do that?

Comment: How are you calling the function? It should return an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT [dbo].[f_InboundCallsPerUser](@p_User, @p_sd , @p_ed)
```

I guess you are probably `EXEC`-ing it. in which case you need to do

```
DECLARE @Result INT
EXEC @Result =[dbo].[f_InboundCallsPerUser] @p_User, @p_sd , @p_ed 
SELECT @Result
```

to see the returned value.

Comment: I see that. It works. What I really want to do is use it in a select statement. Like SELECT name, callmyfunctionhere from NAMELIST.

Comment: Your Comment is truncated but you can use it in a `SELECT` statement like `SELECT name, [dbo].[f_InboundCallsPerUser](name, create_date , modify_date)  as calls FROM sys.objects` although having said that I wouldn't except if you are only using it on small tables. Scalar UDFs that do data access can kill performance.